# Java 7 conexion a Sql Server 2014

Tags: java, sql-server, base-de-datos, jdbc

Estoy tratando de conectarme con java 7 a sql server 2014 y obtengo el siguiente error :

> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed."

el codigo que estoy usando es :

```
driver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
url ="jdbc:sqlserver://Ip:port;databasename=xxx";
user = "xxx";
pass = "xxx";
Class.forName(driver);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

Descarque los archivos .jar de Msdn download [Msdn Descargas](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=11774) y he usado : sqljdbc.jar, sqljdc4.jar, sqljdbc41.jar and sqljdbc42.jar.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomiendo usar http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ para lo que necesitas. Y la falla que aparece es por que tu conexión no la estas haciendo vía SSL sino simplemente por el socket.

Según la documentación de microsoft deberás añadir lo siguiente en tu conexión:

```
String connectionUrl =   
    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +  
     "databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;" +  
     "encrypt=true; trustServerCertificate=false;" +  
     "trustStore=storeName;trustStorePassword=storePassword";
```

O podría ser así

```
String connectionUrl =   
    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +  
     "databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;" +  
     "encrypt=true; trustServerCertificate=false;" +  
     "trustStore=storeName;trustStorePassword=storePassword" +  
     "hostNameInCertificate=hostName";
```

Aquí está la documentación:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879949(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Con jtds, funciona !! gracias-